# How to use NUnit with F# properly?

Tags: f#, nunit, fsunit

I have stucked with the unit testing. I have the following source code:

```
module SampleTest
open FsUnit

open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
[<Category("Category name")>]
type DoSthTest() =

    let mutable state = []

    [<SetUp>]
    member public x.``run before test``() =
        state = []

    [<Test>]
    member x.``add item``() =
        state <- List.append state [1]
        state.Length |> should equal 1
```

In general it runs fine.... but without the [] function.
I got the following exception: Result Message: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: run before test

Does someone know the answer why ?
And the second question is: is it possible to write an unittest without type definition but with the SetUp also function working?
I mean sth like this:

```
module SampleTest

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework


let mutable state = []

[<SetUp>]
let ``run before test``() =
    state = []

[<Test>]
let ``add item``() =
    state <- List.append state [1]
    state.Length |> should equal 1
```

again I got the same exception as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F#, mutable values are assigned using `<-` rather than `=`.

So your Setup method should look like:

```
[<SetUp>]
member public x.``run before test``() =
    state <- []
```

which works fine.

For your second question, this layout works fine for me if you make the same change as above.

Comment: yep, it worksfine now!!! Thanks. I was missing the 'public' modifier after let keyword. I did not know that I can set visibility modifier to function definitions (For OOP it was obvious for me)